# PHPDoc: как указать необязательный параметр и его значение по умолчанию?

Tags: php, phpdoc

Есть функция:

```
/**
 *
 * Summary
 *
 * Description
 *
 * @param string $message Description
 *
 * @return void
 *
 */
function say( $message = 'hi' ) {

    echo $message;

}
```

Как указать в PHPDoc, что параметр `$message` является необязательный и имеет значение `hi`?

---

Я нашёл такие же вопросы в англоязычном сообществе, но там везде ссылаются на следующий абзац из документации:

> Note that the $paramname,... will be shown in the output docs in both the parameter listing AND the function signature. If you are not indicating in the actual code that the parameter is optional (via "$paramname = 'a default value'"), then you should mention in the parameter's description that the parameter is optional.

Этот абзац, к сожалению, я не могу понять:

> Заметьте, что `$paramname,...` будет показываться в результирующей документации как в листинге параметров, так и в сигнатуре функции. Если вы не обозначите в реальном коде этот параметр как необязательный (с помощью «$paramname = 'значение по умолчанию'»), то вы должны упомянуть в описании параметра, что параметр необязательный.

---

Я пробовал указать так:

```
/**
 *
 * @param string $message,... Description
 *
 */
```

Но мой NetBeans подсвечивает это как «Wrong Param Name».

---

Для примера, в JSDoc это делается так:

```
/**
 *
 * @param {string} [message=hi] Description
 *
 */
```

---

Я пробовал по аналогии:

```
/**
 *
 * @param string [$message] Description
 *
 * ...
 *
 * @param string [$message=hi] Description
 *
 * ...
 *
 * @param string [$message='hi'] Description
 *
 * ...
 *
 * @param string [$message="hi"] Description
 *
 */
```

Но ничего не выходит: NetBeans показывает имя параметра в описании, а не как имя параметра.

---

**UPD**

Что-то сразу не догадался подсмотреть у других: заглянул в документацию Yii, в частности в один метод: [ActiveForm::begin()](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/base/Widget.php#L52); но там разработчики никак не обозначают необязательный параметр `$config = []`?

Answer (score 1):

У вас уже задан параметр по умолчанию "Hi"

```
$message = 'hi'
```

Comment: И как это указать в PHPDoc: например, я кодирую в другом файле; смотрю — функция; вызываю документацию по ней (Ctrl+CursorHover), а в документации ничего не сказано про необязательность и значение по умолчанию.

Comment: @RomanGrinyov это уже проблемы менеджера документации и метаданных. Значение по умолчанию уже указано в коде, никаких дополнительных действий не требуется.